# Proof by Contradiction?

Tags: logic

How does one construct the proof by contradiction? I know Direct Proof and Proof by Contrapositive really well but just can't understand proof by contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. The question unfortunately needs a *lot* more context before anyone can attempt to answer it.

Answer (score 6):

Statement: If $p$ is true, then $q$ is true.
Direct Proof: Assume $p$ is true, try to proof $q$ is true.
Contrapositive: Assume $q$ is false, try to proof $p$ is false.
Contradiction: Assume $p$ is true and $q$ is false, try to proof the assumption will lead to result makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

**Brief summary**.  Assume provisionally that the statement you want to prove true is actually false.  Work out some consequences until you arrive at something you **know** is false.  As long as your deductions are all accurate, the only way you could have obtained a false conclusion is if the provisional assumption you made was incorrect.  That is, the statement you want is not false, it is true.

---

**Possible format** (not the only way of setting out this kind of proof) -

**Theorem**.  The statement $S$ is true.

**Proof**.  Assume that $S$ is false.  Then
...$\langle$various deductions$\rangle$...
and therefore $\langle$some conclusion$\rangle$.
But this is false.  $\langle$For example, you might have proved that $0=1$.$\rangle$
Therefore the statement $S$ is true.

---

**Example**.  We observe by calculation that to $8$ significant figures,
$$8+31\sqrt{15}\quad\hbox{and}\quad20\sqrt{41}$$
are both equal to $128.06248$.  Are these numbers really equal?

**Answer**.  No, they are not equal.

**Proof**.  Suppose the contrary, that is,
$$8+31\sqrt{15}=20\sqrt{41}\ .$$
Squaring both sides,
$$14479+496\sqrt{15}=16400\ ,$$
so
$$496\sqrt{15}=1921\ .$$
Squaring both sides again,
$$3690240=3690241\ .$$
But this is false.  Hence our original supposition was false; that is,
$$8+31\sqrt{15}\ne20\sqrt{41}\ .$$

---

**What next?**  There are many examples of proof by contradiction online, please read a few and then try to do some yourself.  Make sure that at some stage you read the two classics of proof by contradiction: $\sqrt2$ is irrational, and there are infinitely many primes.

Good luck!